# What does the first line in an Galileo itinerary mean?

Tags: itineraries, gds

I have the following entry:

```
XXXXXX/15 QSBSB 0293756 AG 99559992 19JUL
```

Could anyone tell me what does each element / word signify?

Comment: My guess, responsible airline and the queuing office and Airline locator.

Answer (score 3):

In one of the Galileo manuals I found the following:

```
MNVZR8/75 ZRHNH C041753 AG 96040232 16MAR
  1.1SMITH/JOHNMR
1. LX 316 C 14AUG ZRHLHR HK1 0705 0755 O*
E MO
** FILED FARE DATA EXISTS **
** VENDOR LOCATOR DATA EXISTS **
** SERVICE INFORMATION EXISTS **
** TINS REMARKS EXIST **
** ELECTRONIC DATA EXISTS **
FONE-ZRHT*0041 1 844 300 300 GALILEO SCHULUNG ZRH
```

And its electronic ticker form is as follows:

```
TKT: 724 9900 395025     NAME: SMITH/JOHNMR
ISSUED: 16FEB09          FOP:CASH
PSEUDO: 0OA9  PLATING CARRIER: LX  ISO: CH  IATA: 96040232
USE CR FLT CLS DATE BRDOFF TIME ST F/B
OPEN LX 316 C 14AUG ZRHLHR 0705 OK CSWISSOW
FARE CHF 1057.00 TAX  36.00 CH TAX  29.00 YR TAX
TOTAL CHF 1122.00
   VALID ON LX/LH ONLY
ZRH LX LON 807.21CSWISSOW NUC807.21END ROE1.30944
RLOC 1G MNVZR8    LX JWQTZD
```

So basically this tells me:

```
XXXXXX/15 QSBSB 0293756 AG 99559992 19JUL
```

| XXXXXX  > PNR ??|

| 15      > ??    |

| QSBSB   >  First 3 letters form the first boarding sector|

| 0293756 >     ??|

| AG 99559992  > Agents IATA code|

| 19JUL  > Itinerary creation date|